# Nativescript: Page outlet router not working

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, nativescript

I'm building a tabview and the `page-outlet-router` or `router-outlet` not showing anything and no errors in the console or the app emulator and even debug chrome

I'm using the latest everything angular/tns/tns-core ( nativescript 6 / angular 8 )

the code:

**Tabs template**

```xml
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">
    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Players Tab'}" name="homeTab">
    </page-router-outlet>
 </TabView>
```

**Tabs Routing:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/(homeTab:home)', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', outlet: 'homeTab', loadChildren: '~/app/pages/home/home.module#HomeModule', component: NSEmptyOutletComponent },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(homeTab:home)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [TabsComponent],
  imports: [
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
```

**The home routing:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
```

**Home template**

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <Button text="home works!" class="btn btn-primary"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Refer the [tns-template-tab-navigation-ng](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/tns-template-tab-navigation-ng) template for clean example, if you still find issues please share a Playground sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is change the `tabs` component selector name to something different than the URL path. For example: "tabs-page".
Also, any other root components used for landing pages should also have different selectors than the corresponding route paths.

The issue is tracked here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1967